# IntentSevice work queue handling

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I have a Xamarin for Android app that I'm writing and I have a situation where I need to send some information from my app to a web service to be saved.  I'm still relatively new to the Android framework, but it seems like an IntentService is a reasonable choice so I can off load that work from my main thread.

However, I'm a little fuzzy on how the IntentService manages the work queue for the requests sent to it.  Specifically, what happens to the work queue requests for the service when there's a failure involved during processing?  For example, in my case, say there's no wifi/3G connection available, the web server is unavailable, etc.  Would I need to catch those issues and resubmit them to the service again or is there a way to handle them internally in the service?

Having read through the Android service docs (http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html), it seems like the requests are serviced as received and discarded; I didn't see any mention about keeping a request in the queue if something happens, re-adding to the queue manually by the developer, etc.

Am I missing something?  Or should I be rolling my own Service class to handle these issues?  Any thoughts would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intent service will only do what you tell it to do inside the `onHandleIntent(Intent intent)` method.  There is no error handling baked in, because it's not a given that all implementations of `IntentService` will be doing network requests or any specific task for that matter.  The only guarantee is that your code inside `onHandleIntent()` will be on a worker thread.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I didn't mean to imply that the service does specific tasks, that was just my example. However, no matter the task being performed, errors/constraints may occur during execution for just about anything except the simplest of tasks. I'm just surprised there isn't a mechanism in place to let the service notify the framework that the request was handled (e.g. possibly a handled flag passed back from the onHandleIntent method, much like the values that can be passed back from onStartCommand). Or at least some docs on how to handle failed requests properly.

Comment: After checking the Android docs again, I think a PendingIntent may be what I'm looking for as it allows a result to be returned from the service. Not sure how I missed that the first time. :)